# python writelines from a list made from .split()

Tags: python, csv

I have a very long string with vertical and horizontal delimiters in this format:

```
[|Bob Hunter|555-5555|B|Polycity|AK|55555||#|Rob Punter|999-5555|B|Bolycity|AZ|55559|rpunter@email.com|#|....and so on...]
```

I would like to generate a list from this long string using split('#') and then write each element as a line to a new text file like so:

```
|Bob Hunter|555-5555|B|Polycity|AK|55555||
|Rob Punter|999-5555|B|Bolycity|AZ|55559|rpunter@email.com|
```

I will then import it into excel and delimit by the pipes.

```
f1 = open(r'C:\Documents\MyData.html','r')
f2 = open(r'C:\Documents\MyData_formatted.txt','w')

lines = f1.read().split("#")
for i in lines:
    f2.writelines(i)

f2.close()
f1.close()
```

However, the txt file remains one line and only a partial amount of the data is written to the file (only about 25% is there). How can I get python to split the data by the # symbol and write each element of the resulting list to a file as a new line?

Comment: can't reproduce, splits fine

Comment: `writelines(i)` is equivalent to `write(i)`, if `i` is a string. you are missing the newlines, basically only removing all occurences of `'#'` from the file. Use `print` or append the newline `write('\n')` after each line. But that does not explain how you get to observe partial data. How do you check the contents?

Comment: just check by printing lines. what does it have ?

Comment: `f2.write(i + '\n')`

Comment: @Jay Parikh It prints a couple of thousand of lines and then stalls out

Comment: @ShaunO your code seems fine. just try as Goyo said, adding '\n' line character.

Comment: Maybe replace the delimiter with a newline instead of splitting?

Comment: @ Goyo; Jay Parikh. Yep. It's working now. The file that was being read was copied from another file and it didn't grab all of the data, hence the cut off. It's formatting perfect now. Post the answer and I'll check it off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your corrected code, I changed `line` variable to `records`, because we're not dealing with lines and just to avoid confusion:

```
records = f1.read()
records = records[1:]          # remove [
records = records[:-1]         # remove ]
records = records.split("#")

for rec in records:
    f2.write(rec + "\n")
```

And since you mentioned you need this data in excel, use csv files and from excel open your csv output file and excel will format your output as needed without you having to do that manually:

```
import csv
w = csv.writer(f2, dialect="excel")
records = [line.replace("|", ",") +"\n" for line in records]

for rec in records:
    w.writerow([rec])
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to check this. I was trying to vet out Fempter's answer but had too many changes after getting the code to work with your solution. Fempter's answer may offer a more refined output but your solution did exactly what I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that before every `#` we should also delete `|`, because without that, after every splitted rocord we will get `||` as first characters in every line. That's why we should split `|#`, not only `#`.

Try this:

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f1:
    text = f1.read().lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split("|#") #remove '[' and ']' from each side

with open('output.txt','w') as f2:
        for line in text:
            f2.write('%s\n' % line) #write to file as string with new line sign
```

Comment: Thank you for this but my code had changed so much after incorporating direprobs solution that I couldn't work your code in without dismantling my script beyond a point I was comfortable with. I finally got things working with the other solution and it did what I asked and I'm gun shy on messing with a working script. However, I do see how your suggestion would yield a more refined output. Thanks!